# Had Moses changed something in the Law as when Deuteronomy 12:15 - 16 is compared to Leviticus 10:10 and 11:4-8?

Tags: mosaic-law, diet, moses, cleanliness

> Deuteronomy 12:15-16
>
> 15
>       Notwithstanding thou mayest kill and eat flesh in all thy gates, whatsoever thy 
>       soul lusteth after, according to the blessing of the Lord thy God which he hath 
>       given thee: the unclean and the clean may eat thereof, as of the roebuck, and 
>       as of the hart.
>
> 16
>
> Only ye shall not eat the blood; ye shall pour it upon the 
>   earth as water.

.

> Leviticus 10:10, 11:4-8
>
> Nevertheless these shall ye not eat of them that chew the cud, or of them 
>       that divide the hoof: as the camel, because he cheweth the cud, but divideth 
>       not the hoof; he is unclean unto you.
>
> And the coney, because he cheweth the cud, but divideth not the hoof; he is 
>       unclean unto you.
>
> And the hare, because he cheweth the cud, but divideth not the hoof; he is 
>       unclean unto you.
>
> And the swine, though he divide the hoof, and be clovenfooted, yet he 
>       cheweth not the cud; he is unclean to you.
>
> Of their flesh shall ye not eat, and their carcase shall ye not touch; they 
>       are unclean to you.

Did Moses change the Levitical dietary law perhaps in favor of helping the oft murmuring and pagan worshiping Children of Israel even going so far as to allow them the pleasure of eating whatsoever their soul lusteth after?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Eating and being eaten are two distinct things.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: No, but observations and clarifications do, and I am simply pointing out an obvious misreading of the given text.

Comment: @lucian OK, I guess your intent was to ask Mushy to clarify or improve the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Had Moses changed  something in the Law as when Deuteronomy 12:15 - 16 is compared  to Leviticus 10:10 and 11:4-8?**

The simple answer is **no**.

First of all, let us look at the texts in question more closely.

> 15 “However, you may slaughter and eat meat within any of your towns, as much as you desire, according to the blessing of the Lord your God that he has given you. The unclean and the clean may eat of it, as of the gazelle and as of the deer. 16 Only you shall not eat the blood; you shall pour it out on the earth like water. - [Deuteronomy 12:15-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+12%3A15-16&version=ESV)
>
> 8 Then the Lord said to Aaron, 9 “You and your sons are not to drink wine or other fermented drink whenever you go into the tent of meeting, or you will die. This is a lasting ordinance for the generations to come, 10 so that you can distinguish between the holy and the common, between the unclean and the clean, 11 and so you can teach the Israelites all the decrees the Lord has given them through Moses.” - [Leviticus 10:8-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+10%3A8-11&version=NIV)
>
> 4 “‘There are some that only chew the cud or only have a divided hoof, but you must not eat them. The camel, though it chews the cud, does not have a divided hoof; it is ceremonially unclean for you. 5 The hyrax, though it chews the cud, does not have a divided hoof; it is unclean for you. 6 The rabbit, though it chews the cud, does not have a divided hoof; it is unclean for you. 7 And the pig, though it has a divided hoof, does not chew the cud; it is unclean for you. 8 You must not eat their meat or touch their carcasses; they are unclean for you. - [Leviticus 11:4-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+11%3A4-8&version=NIV)

In all three biblical quotes, Moses is in the mists of defining and explaining what the Law allows and does not allows when it comes to dietary rules for the People of God.

First of all, Moses explains that both clean and unclean amongst the Ancient Israelites may eat the (clean) flesh of animals, which are permitted to be eaten. Here he is simply making a statement. Both those who are clean and those whose are ritually unclean may eat the flesh of animals, but not their blood. Sorry, no blood sausage is permitted. The blood of animals must be poured on the ground.

In both the Leviticus quotes, Moses explains what constitutes is permitted to be eaten or drunk according to the rules of the Law.

For example, if one wishes to go into the tent of meeting, one must not drink fermented beverages prior to doing so. Doing so will make one common and unclean.

The last quote involving Leviticus, Moses is explaining what constitutes unclean animals which may **not** be eaten by the Chosen People. Again eating unclean animals will make one ritually unclean according to the Law.

I like to look at Moses division between clean and unclean animals as something of being done as a medial officer to keep the People of God healthy. For example, pigs are notorious for passing on worms to other hosts, people included.

Swine flesh if eaten by non-Jewish people must always be well cooked to avoid any contamination from various [parasites](https://www.oie.int/doc/ged/D9157.PDF) of this animal. Moses is simply keeping the Ancient Israelites pure and healthy through dietary edicts!

To stay clean do not eat unclean animals!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be misreading the passages.  Those who are *ceremonially clean* and those who are not (*those who have been contaminated*) may both eat of whatever *clean* animals that they desire.

Comment: Welcome to ChristianitySE. Your answer as written may be correct, and it may not, but since it is not supported that is unclear.  Please support your answer.   [How to write a good answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) explains how to do that.